# Temporary contacts for Android

Tags: android, contact-manager

I've asked for [an Android Phone app that shows caller context](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/52755/android-phone-app-that-shows-caller-context), but then I realized it would be simpler to make (and thus with a higher probability of already having been made) a way to add contacts temporarily to a phone's Contacts List, such that I would add the person now and it would be deleted after a month or so (perhaps ideally I would define that term when adding the contact).

Actually, just a way to separate "permanent" contacts from transactional with a quick-add and quick-delete options would be sufficient for the job.

I would rather pay, say, 10/15 bucks than use an app full of ads and trackers.

Comment: How much can it cost? Are ads/trackers in the app acceptable (considering contact info is sensible data)?

Comment: I don't know. I would rather pay, say, 10/15 bucks than use an app full of ads and trackers. But I'm a cheapo and hard to please and would probably dislike anything.

Comment: When a contact is created, you can add it to a group - at least in the old android versions i use... So create a group called "Temp". When you add such contacts, assign them to that group. Then delete all contacts in "Temp" as often as you like.